# Identity theorem for holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to check whether there exists a holomorphic function $$f:U_{1+\epsilon}(0)\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}_{\ge 2}$ such that

$$
| f^{(n)}(0)|\ge (n!)^2.
$$

I'm sure that I have to use the identity theorem, but I don't know how to start.

Any help would be great!

Thyrð

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that $U_{1+\varepsilon}(0)$ is the open disk of radius $1+\varepsilon$ centered at $0$. According to the Cauchy integral formula,
$$ f^{(n)}(0)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}\;dz $$
which implies that
$$ |f^{(n)}(0)|\leq n!\sup_{|z|=1}|f(z)| $$

This expression will be less than $(n!)^2$ for all sufficiently large $n$ (depending on $f$), so no such function exists.

Comment: I have another one, same premises. Check if $f$ is holomorphic such that $$ f\left(\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right) = \left(\frac{1}{n^2} -1\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

Comment: It's probably best to make that a new question, as I don't know whether the above method will work.